# Why does this boolean return true

Tags: php, function, boolean, boolean-logic

I was doing a coding challange that i passed but when i saw this solution is was stuned because i did not see how this could work because the expression returns false but the function self returns true, can someone explain to me why this is the case.

Here is the coding question

Check to see if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's. The method must return a boolean and be case insensitive. The string can contain any char.

Examples input/output

```
XO("ooxx") => true
XO("xooxx") => false
XO("ooxXm") => true
XO("zpzpzpp") => true // when no 'x' and 'o' is present should return true
XO("zzoo") => false
```

this was my solution

```
function XO($s) {
  
  $ka = false; 
  
  $s = strtolower($s);
  
  if (strpbrk($s,'x') || strpbrk($s,'o')) {
    
    if (substr_count($s,'x') == substr_count($s,'o')){
      $ka = true;
    }
    
  }
  else {
    $ka = true;
  }
  
  return $ka ;
}
```

and this is the solution that some else had posted

```
function SO(string $s):bool {
    return substr_count(strtolower($s),'o')==substr_count(strtolower($s),'x');
}
```

And this does the as mine solution even when the character are 'zzz' it returns true. But how can some one explain this to me

Comment: Because 0 still equals 0?

Comment: Not sure what the exact doubt is. Type hints and `strtolower()` caching aside, it's pretty much the same you do, but it skips redundant checks and variables.

Comment: _even when the character are 'zzz' it returns true_  because count of `o` 0 is `==` count of `x` 0.

Comment: To me the hardest part of the problem seems to be the unspecified encoding scheme.

Comment: @aynber yes that was it thanks